# How to add an integer plus another number without a loop

Tags: python, discord.py

I have xp = 5 above all. What happens now is it just returns 10 each time, and never adds past that. I know that's because it's not in a loop, but in my situation, I'm unable to do this in a loop.

```
if xp < 50:
    xp += 5
    print(xp)
elif xp == 50:
    cursor.execute('UPDATE level_system SET level = %s WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s',
                   (result2[0] + 1, user_id, guild_id))
    conn.commit()
    await message.channel.send(
        f"Nice, {message.author.mention}, You've leveled up to level {result2[0] + 1}!")
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: Then copy-paste the code X number of times like if it was in a loop?

Comment: And especially *why* "can't you use a loop"? What should this be driving a car without being able to use the steering wheel? What should be the purpose of this?

Comment: You could do a while loop first (while xp < 50, and increment xp +=5 inside that while loop) and write what happens if xp is equal to 50 with an if xp ==50 statement below your while loop.

Comment: @Pat-Laugh That's ridiculous, why on earth would I do that?

Comment: Everyone, I can not use a while loop because if you know anything about discord.py and its' on message event, if I used a while loop, it would just repeat it over and over and over

Comment: This appears to need more context to be answerable in a meaningful way. Even if discord.py is assumed.

Comment: Run the loop BEFORE the `discord.py` part.

Comment: i think, since this is not inside of a loop? since ur xp is less than 50 it gets added 5 and then becomes 10 and stops, unless u re run the if statement, xp will b new 10 ,OR mayb somewhere else u are setting xp to 5 and thats y again when loop is re run ur 
adding 5 to the xp in the if statement and becoming 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the whole code it's just a shot in the dark, but you say, "I have xp = 5 above all. What happens now is it just returns 10 each time".

So, are you sure that *the xp = 5 assignment isn't also executed each time?* So that each time you restart from 5, add 5, and that is why you always get 10 and nothing else?

Comment: I put the xp = 5 outside of the function and put global xp where it needed to be inside of it